# Possible Sanskrit word "pas" as declension case

Tags: grammar, sanskrit, declension

I would like to ask if it is possible that the word ***pas***, which I think could be a Sanskrit word, is a declined case of an existing word (e.g. the nominative or vocative case).

If not, could it be a word by itself (as is)?

According to [this online dictionary](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=pas&lang=sans&action=Search), *pas* could be the nominative singular of *pa* or *pā*, but the declension of these words seems to be different, with the nominative ending with *ḥ*.

Comment: That’s the same thing – _h_ is just a word-final (sandhi-conditioned) variant of _s_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanskrit has two homophonic verbal roots pā, one meaning “to protect”, the other “to drink”. In both meanings they can occur as the second element of noun+verb compounds like nŗ-pa- “protecting men” or madhu-pa- “drinking honey”. As is normal in Sanskrit dictionaries, these words are cited as stems (without case endings); the nominative singular adds the ending -s (context form) or -ḥ (pausal form). pas and paḥ do not occur on their own as nouns, but they do occur in compounds.

Comment: can you clarify about pā & pa? At the beginning you only mention the former, the examples you give are both the latter, and then at the end you mention both. If it's just that both occur in both ablaut grades it would probably be worth stating that explicitly

Comment: @Tristan. Yes, ablaut.

Comment: Currently favoured theory is that both go back to IE *peH3 in ablaut with *pH3.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the nominative singular ending in Sanskrit is *-ḥ*. As @JanusBahsJacquet clarified, it derives from an earlier *-s*. However, *-ḥ* superficially manifests as such almost exclusively if the word to which it is added is an isolated word or if it ends the sentence. Whenever the next word in the sentence starts with a voiceless dental (i.e. *t*, *th*), then *-ḥ* reverts back to *-s*. This is part of a wider phenomenon known as **external sandhi**.

It is therefore possible, at least in theory, for a form lik *paḥ* to represent the nominative (from a root *pa-* or *pas-*).

Comment: do you mean voiceless dentals (seeing as your examples are t & th)?

Comment: @Tristan. Yes, I am sorry. You are of course right, I meant voiceless dentals.

Comment: Thank you @Tochtli. When you say that the -_ḥ_ "derives from an earler -_s_", do you mean that the -_s_ was used in an older (more ancient) form of Sanskrit?

If so, could you provide references to some examples?

Comment: @user3764418 _-s_ is the Proto-Indo-European nominative ending (you can see it in Latin _-us_, Greek _-os_, etc.). At some point before the earliest attested stage of Vedic Sanskrit, a sound change occurred in Indo-Iranian languages that changed _Vs#_ to _Vh#_, but it took place before the earliest written documents.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How is it possible to know this if there are no written documents to attest it?

Comment: @user3764418 Comparation of related languages. That’s how reconstructive historical linguistics work. Have a read about [the comparative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_method).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. The shift of final -s (also -r) to -ḥ in pausal position is specific to Old Indian (Vedic and Sanskrit). It is independent of the Iranian shift of s to h in almost all positions.

Comment: Phonetic "ḥ" does not just derive from historically earlier *s*, it derives from synchronic /s/. Superficial [h] has two sources, as we can tell that the n.s. suffix is /s/ because before a voiced segment in external sandhi, /as/ becomes [o] but /ar/ become remains [ar].

Comment: @user3764418 Examples of the shift *-s* > *-ḥ* are very common. It happens in the nominative singular of many nouns and adjectives whose stem ends in a vowel, such as नरः *náraḥ* 'man' (< Proto-Indo-Iranian **náras*), or nouns originally ending in **-s*, like उषाः *uṣā́ḥ* 'dawn' (< PIIr. **Hušā́s*); notice the genitive singular of this noun is उषसः *uṣásaḥ* (< **Hušás-as*), where the *s* of the stem reappears because it is no longer in final position, but the final **-s* of the genetive ending regularly becomes *-ḥ*.